# How to re-use Hibernate Validation with custom validators in both Spring MVC and API layer

Tags: spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Lets say that i have an application that front-end is built using Spring MVC.
That same application exposes API for integration purposes.

Errors in Web are shown by using Spring MVC form:error tags by using JSR-303 and Hibernate validator with custom constraints.

Everything is fine, but i want to reuse the same validation in my API layer, and fail with error codes if my validation fails.

Lets say i have a POJO object (just an example):

```
@ValidDomainObject
public class DomainObject {

    public String superSetting;

    public String anotherSetting;

    public String getSuperSetting() {
        return superSetting;
    }

    public void setSuperSetting(String superSetting) {
        this.superSetting = superSetting;
    }

    public String getAnotherSetting() {
        return anotherSetting;
    }

    public void setAnotherSetting(String anotherSetting) {
        this.anotherSetting = anotherSetting;
    }

}
```

And @ValidDomainObject is validated by this Validator:

```
public class DomainObjectValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDomainObject, DomainObject> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ValidDomainObject constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final DomainObject obj, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        if (obj.getAnotherSetting().equals(obj.getSuperSetting())) {
            context
                    .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{message.to.show}")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

All is fine in the front MVC tier - i define message.to.show in language files to resolve to something like "Cannot set X to Y" and user sees the message on the page.

So how do i achieve same thing in the API layer? If i want to throw ServiceFault with ErrorCodes.PROPERTIES_MATCH or similar ?

I could simply use:

```
   Set<ConstraintViolation<DomainObject>> validationErrors = validator.validate(domainObject);
```

And then loop the retrieved set checking for messages and building faults with given error codes. But that seems like front-end coupling with API  layer.

I could do vice versa:

```
      context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
ErrorCodes.PROPERTIES_MATCH.toString()) .addConstraintViolation();
```

But then, the message structure for front end is not as the other messages, and no interpolation.

What would be the best approach ?

Comment: take a look how it's done in [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/jsr-303.html)